# setting a timeout for every new socket node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, timeout

As I'm building my own `http module` relying on `net module`, I want to set a timeout for every new socket.
I build the following:

```
server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
          if(server.timeout==null){
                server.timeout=120000;
                if(server.timeoutCallBack==null){
                    server.timeoutCallBack=function(){socket.destroy();};
                }
            }
          socket.setTimeout(server.timeout,server.timeoutCallBack());
```

so if the user of my server, set a new timeout duration , it will use it. if not, it has a default value of 2 minutes.

My problem is that my server doesn't serve the first connection, just the second. I mean, for the first http message it gets, it doesn't invoke my :

```
            socket.on("data", function (data) {
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you passed to socket.setTimeout as your callback is the **result** of `server.timeoutCallBack()`, which is `undefined`. Instead of calling `timeoutCallBack` 2 minutes after that line, you called it on that line and `setTimeout` of nothing.

You should pass a reference to a function to `setTimeout` instead:

```
socket.setTimeout(server.timeout,server.timeoutCallBack);
```